# Wordpress add a traditional callback

Tags: php, wordpress

`add_filter( 'simple_page_ordering_limit', function($number) { return 5; } );`

> This example uses PHP 5.3+ callback functions, so if you're still on
>   PHP 5.2, you'll need to add a traditional callback.

Can someone help to convert it to traditional callback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses an [anonymous function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) which is obviously not supported. You can do it like this;

```
function callback_function($number) {
    return 5;
}

add_filter( 'simple_page_ordering_limit', 'callback_function');
```

Comment: I tired this its still not working, I am sure the solution you gave is right. Same plugin working for me on different host, what could be the issue ?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? I know nothing of Wordpress but as [demonstrated here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) it should work.

Comment: I tried the same function.
This is the Wordpress plugin I am having problem with.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your direct implementation of the fix? You need to declare the function properly, as in not in a other function, and some other conditions I could not find.